# Update meta_key with ajax in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms, function, advanced-custom-fields

I want to update `meta_key` with `ajax` in wordpress i use this form

this is my code but not work for me

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'ajax_the_clike' );
function ajax_the_clike() { 
?>
<script>
var ajaxurl = 'http://'+window.location.host+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
var formd = "#like";
  $(formd).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(formd).attr('action'),
      type: $(formd).attr('method'),
      data: $(formd).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!");
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log("FAILURE");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<?php 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_the_clike', 'the_clike'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE} 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_the_clike', 'the_clike');
function the_clike() {
    echo '<form action="'.site_url() .'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="post" id="like">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="VoteUp" id="submit" name="submits">';
        
    if(isset($_POST['submits'])){
        $postsid = get_the_ID();
        $addone = get_field('like');
        $addone++;
        update_field('field_5f009fe6d7067' ,$addone, $postsid);
    }
echo '</form><p> Like : '; if(get_field('like')) { the_field('like');}else{echo '0';} echo '</p>';
}
?>
```

I using a Advanced custom field plugin

Where is wrong? How do I solve this problem?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please include details of the problem you are having and the debugging you have already done. Saying the code does "*not work for me*" doesn't tell us anything... are you getting an error message? A blank screen? Does the ajax call fail or is the value not being saved? etc

Comment: the problem is `ajax call`, after click a submit just get to `mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and show `0`  for me